# ToggleButton - How Do I Manually Call Its onClick Listener?

Tags: android

I have created a custom View which is a descendent of ToggleButton. I want my custom view to have two states i.e. on and off just like ToggleButton but I want to MANUALLY change its state once my custom view has been clicked.

The way I have done this so far is to override the performClick() method but in my performClick() method I want to be able to call the assigned onClick listener, so my question is how do I call my custom view's onClick listener? (I bet there's an obvious answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I just override toggle().